# Order of weekdays in a bar chart using lubridate and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

When creating a bar plot where the x-axis is Weekdays (using lubridate and ggplot), the order of my weekdays does't follow the chronological "mon, tues, wed... "

I've tried to replicate the problem but as you can see below, in my replication, the order of labels on the x-axis if fine.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

my_data <- data.frame(dates = sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100), 
                      group = rep(c(1,2,3,4), times = 5)) 
my_data <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(Weekdays = wday(dates, label = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(Weekdays != "Sat" &
           Weekdays != "Sun")


ggplot(my_data, aes(Weekdays))+
  geom_bar()+
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

Output:

[image]

The code below is what I have used with the real data. As you can see the week days are not in order. I'm not sure where my actual code differs from the attempted replication above.

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- filter(df, wday != "Sat")

ggplot(df1, aes(x = wday))+
  geom_bar()+
  facet_wrap(~Grouping)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, hjust = 1))
```

Output:

[image]

Any help / advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to convert to factor and reorder the levels

Comment: Can you check your data type for your own dataframe's `wday` variable? If you run `str(my_data)` on your reproducible data above you see that `lubridate` has made it an ordered factor. I imagine in your data it's a character variable or unordered factor. Then would just need corrected as @Sotos mentions above (or see if in your code it's converted to character by mistake).

Comment: Agreed with above comments - just to clarify, the "wrong" order of weekdays is alphabetical order which is the default ordering that ggplot will plot bars for an unordered factor or character variable. The way to convert a character or unordered factor to an ordered factor would be something like `weekdays = factor(weekdays, levels = c('Monday','Tuesday',<etc>)`

Comment: That worked perfectly (thanks). It is curious (perhaps someone can explain) that with the code that I pasted above to replicate the problem, lubridate created a variable class "ordered" "factor" (hence the correct order of days) but when I used the same code on my actual data, it created a variable class "character" for the weekdays. Why the inconsistency?

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be the solution

```
my_data %>% 
  mutate(weekday = fct_reorder(weekdays(dates, abbreviate = TRUE), # generating week days
                               wday(dates))) %>% 
  filter(!weekday %in% c("Sat", "Sun")) %>% # here you filter saturday and sunday
  ggplot(aes(weekday)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~ group)
```

As you can see, the wday function gives the ordered numbers that can be used with fct_reorder function.